# Color grading ; Anybody familiar working with Da-Vinci Resolve?

Tags: video, editing, video-editor, color-correction

I've heard of this tool, [Blackmagic's Da vinci](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) resolve, as its available for free from the site but the Package including its consoles and all costs much. Is there anybody here familiar with this Da-vinci resolve.

Question is , is it feasible to work with the free version (without the consoles) for a small scale video project ?

Is there any courses or online training available for this ?

Expecting feedbacks.. and affordable alternatives for color grading..

Answer (score 1):

### *Got it.. ... I am sharing what i found here for everyone.May be someone needy finds it useful someday ;-)*

[image]

**Q1 was : Can  DaVinci Resolve be used without a panel?**

Ans: Yes.

DaVinci Resolve has been designed to be used with the DaVinci Resolve control panel but can also be used with a mouse or a pen and tablet. There are third party control panels that can also be used with Resolve.

However, there is a significant advantage in terms of speed and ease of grading by using the DaVinci Resolve control panel as it has been specifically designed for Resolve and has the fullest implementation of the feature set. Grading with the DaVinci Resolve control panels will allow you more time to finesse your grades and make and compare different grades for each shot.

**Q2: Any training or tutorials available ?**

Ans : Plenty, but as said earlier without the console , things will gt tricky.

[Here](http://software.blackmagicdesign.com/DaVinciResolve/Manual/Resolve_9_Manual_2012-08-31.pdf) is the link for the official manual.

**Additional Notes:**

This , from what i understand is a truly dedicated color grading system, not for editors but colorists and the color specialists of the industry.

What i still don't know is how is the product available for purchase.. Checked out the Official site, but only 2 dealers found in my country. :-(

Well that's it, i am downloading. 
Will update after using...
Cheerio..